# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not showing in intellisense

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not showing in intellisense.
Even added:

```
implementation : 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

or

```
implementation : 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
```

After sync :
error :

```
Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0
```

or

```
Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1

Show in file
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation of the [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library, please use the latest versions for you dependencies like this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from [Here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/125)

resolve these issue by using separated dependencies

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.0'
```